# How to fix 500 Internal Server Error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been developing app using Ruby on Rails. I put the csv download button so when I click this button, then csv file will download as I want. For this, I defined 3 models. First model name is unit.rb, second is prisoner.rb and third is volunteer.rb. And I made an association for 3 models.
In the unit.rb, belongs_to :course belongs_to :prisoner belongs_to :volunteer, and in the prisoner.rb, has_many :units, inverse_of: :prisoner, dependent: :destroy has_many :volunteers, through: :units , and in the volunteer.rb, has_many :units, inverse_of: :volunteer has_many :prisoners, through: :units.
But when I click the download button, I'm facing 500 internal error

```
def self.to_csv
attributes = %w{course sub_course prisoner volunteer mailing_date return_date reader_mailing_date reader_return_date created_at}

CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
  csv << attributes

  all.each do |unit|
    csv << attributes.map do |attr| 
      if attr == 'course'
        unit.course.try(:title)
      elsif attr == 'sub_course'
        unit.sub_course
      elsif attr == 'prisoner'
        unit.prisoner.name
      elsif attr == 'volunteer'
        unit.volunteer.name
      elsif attr == 'mailing_date'
        unit.mailing_date
      elsif attr == 'return_date'
        unit.return_date
      elsif attr == 'reader_mailing_date'
        unit.reader_mailing_date
      elsif attr == 'reader_return_date'
        unit.reader_return_date
      else
        unit.created_at
      end
    end
  end
end
```

end

Please help me if anyone knows this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. Can you check your ``logs/development`` file and post any error that you see following the 500 error? It should be dumping details of the actual error raised.

Comment: Ok, hold on. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any error  http://prntscr.com/tat2ia

Comment: But I'm facing this screen. http://prntscr.com/tat136      Please help me, I don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: you need to look later in the log file to see the error, the screenshot you showed is too early. The error should be right at the end of the log file after the request 'bombed'

Comment: I just saw this error. http://prntscr.com/tat2ub

Comment: Please let me know if you know this.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/tat7i4    http://prntscr.com/tat7rb    http://prntscr.com/tat7yd

Comment: I don't see a 500 error that you mentioned, in fact the request appears to have succeeded with a 200 response. What server are you running on? You appear to need more memory than you are assigned.

Comment: Hi, few things: 1) Do the operation that causes the 500 error and then **immediately** look at the bottom of the log and post what you see. 2) Please add the text of the log/error to the question, don't post images. 3) Check the Heroku docs (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-memory-use) for info about possible causes of the memory error that you are seeing, as there are several possible causes. What versions of Rails and Ruby are you using?

Comment: It deployed to the heroku

Comment: 2020-07-03T02:49:23.861769+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1082ms (ActiveRecord: 73.0ms)

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.4.1

Comment: 1) Do the operation that causes the 500 error and then immediately look at the bottom of the log and post what you see.   -> I can see this. http://prntscr.com/tav2ab

Comment: so on line 34 of unit.rb, you're calling `name` on a variable that has the value nil. Since I don't know what's on line 34 of unit.rb, you will have to figure out why the variable has the value nil when you (probably) didn't expect it to.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/tavx76

Comment: http://prntscr.com/tavxug

Comment: As you can see in 2 images, I called the name function of the Volunteer model. What's wrong? Please let me know. Many Thanks.

Comment: @HarmonSkiles the error is that `unit.volunteer` is `nil`, which is why the error you can see in the screenshot is `NoMethodError (undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass)`. That means the ruby code is calling `nil.name` which means `unit.volunteer` is `nil`. Just check whether `unit.volunteer_id` is set to NULL in this case or not. If it is expected behaviour for some units not to have volunteers, you should use `unit.volunteer.try(:name)`

Comment: Thanks for your message, if I open that code line, http://prntscr.com/taybuf      then, I got below message.  http://prntscr.com/tayaqv        I have just checked volunteer table data, so it's empty. What's your opinion? I'm very not clear for now. Please let me know and thank you very much!!! I'm waiting...

Comment: There's likely something else breaking then. Can you look for it in the logs? Also, I'd recommend doing all this debugging in your localhost, not on heroku. That'll make things faster

Comment: Yes, thanks. I already checked at all, so I fixed as you mentioned. Thanks again. But I have one issue yet. When I click the download button, I'm facing timeout error(503). http://prntscr.com/tb2cql     When I remove those lines, then I can't see any timeout error, but if I back it, I face timeout error. Omg. Do you have any option for this? I'm really hard for this issue. Thanks. I'm waiting for your good opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I kept seeing '500 Internal Server Error' when testing stripe webhooks with ngrok, the problem seems to be that I had

```rb
status 200
# Gives: 500 Internal Server Error
```

but what I needed was

```rb
head 200
# Gives: 200 OK
```